# retrieve youtube channels based on username

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve youtube channels based on username. Username can be mine or even others. Tried youtube APIExplorer provided at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list to retrieve channel list, set part=contentDetails and forUsername=username (mine and others). In the response channelId is not being retrieved. I am getting ChannelId when i search video using apiexplorer provided at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list.

Did i miss to set any input parameters for channels list? Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Spelling of contentDetails in part= ?

Comment: @tariksbl sorry, it's a typo.